# C# SQL not showing all the data i have drawn in

Tags: c#, sql

Hi i am unable to show all results of the tables in the label.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CN.ClientID, CN.GivenName1, CN.Surname, CI.DateOfBirth FROM [RioOds].dbo.ClientIndex CI LEFT JOIN [RioOds].[dbo].[ClientName] CN ON CN.ClientID = CI.ClientID AND CN.AliasType = '1' AND CN.EndDate IS NULL WHERE CN.ClientID =" + ClientIDTxt.Text + ";", myConnection);
        ResultsLabel.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

I am Trying to write the results of the query into ResultsLabel, only shows the clientID... Any help or ideas?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what `ExecuteScalar()` does. A scalar is a one-dimensional result of one row, i.e. one value. You may want to use `ExecuteReader()`.

Comment: You can't use `ExecuteScalar()` if what you are expecting is not a scalar value

Comment: @CodeCaster exactly :-)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html), careful with this.

Comment: @CodeCaster The ExecuteReader() isnt working. It is showing System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader in the Text Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all.. what ever you are doing to try by these code `is not a good way to doing such` .. but if you want only solution than here is the solution ..

```
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "";
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CN.ClientID, CN.GivenName1, CN.Surname, CI.DateOfBirth FROM [RioOds].dbo.ClientIndex CI LEFT JOIN [RioOds].[dbo].[ClientName] CN ON CN.ClientID = CI.ClientID AND CN.AliasType = '1' AND CN.EndDate IS NULL WHERE CN.ClientID =" + ClientIDTxt.Text + ";", myConnection);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (i!=0)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            sb.Append(reader[i].ToString());
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    ResultsLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Note: ExecuteScalar returns only`first column of first row`(only one value) as result